# TypoScript Condition Syntax

Tags: typoscript

I am new to Typo3 and TypoScript. I try a simple condition, but I fail: I NEED HELP!

My condition:

```
["HELP" == "HELP"]
  templateName = Root
[else]
  templateName = Sub
[end]
```

The condition is in a FLUIDTEMPLATE on a Page:

```
page = PAGE
page {
  ...
  10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
  10 {
    ...
    ["HELP" == "HELP"]
      templateName = Root
    [else]
      templateName = Sub
    [end]
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

I also tried

```
templateName = Root
["HELP" == "ELP"]
templateName = Sub
[END]
```

I was not able to find an understandable explanation.

I tested it with line comments, but it seems it executes both cases always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the indention is just a shortcut in TypoScript you can't insert conditions on other levels than root.

the correct syntax to your example would be:

```
page = PAGE
page {
  ...
  10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
  10 {
    ...
    templateName = Sub
    ...
  }
  ...
}
["HELP" == "HELP"]
  page.10.templateName = Root
[else]
  page.10.templateName = Sub
[end]
```

If you have defined the default value above you could omit the else part.